# When does C++ allocate/deallocate string literals?

Tags: c++, memory-management

When is the string literal "hello" allocated and deallocated during the lifetime of the program in this example?

```
init(char **s)
{
  *s = "hello";
}

int f()
{
  char *s = 0;
  init(&s);
  printf("%s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The string literal is initialised into a read-only memory segment by the compiler. There is no initialisation or removal done at run-time.

Comment: The compiler may copy the contents of the string literal into *local storage* (the stack), thus there is some initialization.  To prevent this, I declare variables as `const static char text[] = "hello";`.  
Also, the read-only segment may also be the executable segment.

Comment: String literals might be in read-only memory, but that is compiler dependent.  So modifying a string literal, like in the code in the question, has undefined behavior but it might work.

Comment: @Thomas. I don;t believe any compiler would copy the string onto the stack that seems rather a redundant operation to me.

Comment: @Thams, @David: Yes the compiler may choose not to use read-only segment (as said an implementation detail). But from the programmers standpoint you should always consider it as a read-only as the type is actually 'char const*' and is only converted to 'char*' for backward compatability with C, and as noted any modification is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

They are not allocated but instead stored in the DATA segment of the executable.

Comment: FYI, the C and C++ languages don't require a *DATA* segment.  The specification states that string literals are constants, but leaves their storage area up to the translator.

Comment: Re *"in the DATA segment"*: Perhaps qualify that in the answer? Such strings may be [stored in program memory](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) on a [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture). Some systems [don't have a DATA segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is an operating system, the memory containing the string literal is allocated when the OS loads the executable and deallocated when the OS unloads the executable. Exactly when this happens depends on the type of executable (program, shared library, etc.) and the OS.