# Return pointer to a temporary in C

Tags: c, pointers, return, temporary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [returning a pointer to a literal (or constant) character array (string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836534/returning-a-pointer-to-a-literal-or-constant-character-array-string)

Is the code below correct?

```
const char* state2Str(enum State state)
{
   switch (state)
   {
      case stateStopped: return "START";
      case stateRunning: return "RUNNING";
      default: return "UNKNOWN";
   }
}

printf("State is: %s\n", state2Str(stateRunning));
```

What worries me is that the function return a pointer to a temporary object. What is the lifetime of such return values? Language is C89.

Comment: A string literal is NOT a temporary object. Its always in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is fine.  You're returning a pointer to a string literal which will be valid for the duration of your program.

From the C89 standard:

> 3.1.4 String literals
>
> A character string literal has static storage duration and type
>   ``array of char ,'' and is initialized with the given characters.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of the code in your question, you are *not* returning pointers to temporaries. You are returning a pointer to a string literal which is stored either among the code or among the global data. The duration of all string literals is the lifetime of the program.