# why pointer change exactly?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Any body has any idea why this code print `a` and not `b`?

I tested that value of `mainArea.root->rightBro` changes when i `cout` something. but why?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct triangle{
    triangle *rightBro; 
};

struct area{
    triangle *root;
} mainArea;

void initialize(){
    triangle root;
    mainArea.root = &root;
}

int main()
{
        initialize();

        mainArea.root->rightBro = NULL ;

        if (mainArea.root->rightBro == NULL) cout << "a" << endl;
        if (mainArea.root->rightBro == NULL) cout << "b" << endl;      
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ pointer to objects which go out of scope when function returns - why does this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591664/c-pointer-to-objects-which-go-out-of-scope-when-function-returns-why-does-th)

Answer (score 10):

You are storing a pointer to a local variable from within `initialize`. After the function returns that memory address is no longer valid to access through the pointer -- your program invokes undefined behavior (UB) when it dereferences `mainArea.root` inside `main`.

By definition, when UB is invoked anything can happen. What you see is some version of anything.

For practical programming purposes, please stop reading here. If you are curious why you are getting specifically this type of behavior, here's an explanation:

What happens in practice is that `mainArea.root` is left pointing to an "unused" address on the stack just after the stack frame for `main`. When you invoke `operator<<` a new stack frame is allocated, which overlaps the memory pointed to by `mainArea.root`. `operator<<`'s (stack-allocated) local variables overwrite the contents of that memory, which from the viewpoint of `main` results in seeing modified values.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
void initialize(){
    triangle root;
    mainArea.root = &root;
}
```

Is causing undefined behavior.

The variable `triangle root;` only lasts as long as the function is being executed. Once the function returns it no longer exists. Thus `mainArea.root` points at random mememory that can be re-used for anything.

Thus any use of `mainArea.root` after the function exits is undefined behavior. Meaning the application can do anything.