# How do you write formatted output, as from printf, into a string?

Tags: c, formatting, char, constants

```
const char* strrep(listing list) {
//https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836534/9295513
char* retVal = //...
return retVal;
}
```

I have a struct type called `listing`. Is there a way to format elements as if by calling `printf` with `("%d %d %s...", list->elem_one, list->elem_two, list->elem_three...)` but write the output to an array of `char` instead of to standard output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you want is `snprintf`.  It creates a formatted string and writes it to the given `char *` argument with a given size instead of to stdout.

For example:

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d %d %s...", list->elem_one, list->elem_two, list->elem_three...);
char *retVal = malloc(len+1);
snprintf(retval, len+1, "%d %d %s...", list->elem_one, list->elem_two, list->elem_three...);
```

The first call is used to figure out how much space is needed.  Then you can allocate the proper amount of space and call `snprintf` again to create the formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

If I read that right, you're looking to print into a buffer instead of out to the console or a file. If that's the case, you'd want to use `sprintf`, or it's bounded cousin `snprintf`. Here's an example from the [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) website:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char buffer [50];
  int n, a=5, b=3;
  n=sprintf (buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a+b);
  printf ("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n",buffer,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that `sprintf` automatically appends a null terminator, but it's still up to you to make sure the total length of the string can fit into the given buffer.